# How to create opportunity from an incoming mail in Odoo 11?

Tags: customization, odoo, odoo-11

In odoo 9 we can create opportunity from an incoming mail, but this feature is not available in Odoo 11, Any idea how can i achieve this functionality in Odoo 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, it's quite simple, Go to settings>email>aliases, select your email aliases, click edit and add default value as {'type': 'opportunity'}.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this one?
If yes, it will be not shown until option "Manually Assignation of Incoming Emails" checkmarked.

[image: Option Manually Assignation of Incoming Emails]

Comment: No, We can create leads from an incoming mail, My question is that can we create Opportunity from an incoming mail.